# send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python, django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a notification feature in Django, using `fcm-django`. I am able to run my code on localhost (development server) but when I deployed the same code to the production server, it's throwing the error:

> send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

models.py:

```
class All_Device_Notification(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    link = models.TextField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        filtered_users = User.objects.all()
        devices = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user__in=list(filtered_users))
        devices.send_message(title=self.title, body=self.description, click_action=self.link)
        super(All_Device_Notification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I am compiling the code on localhost (development server) and it was working well, then why am I facing the error in the production server?

Comment: `send_message` is called on a queryset, not an individual object. Also, just do `.filter(user__in=filtered_users)` it is much faster (it creates a join in the db instead of reading all the users from the database and then not doing anything with them).

Comment: See the documentation at https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `fcm-django < 1` on the development server but latest on the production server.

The fix for the issue on the production server is to restrict the version in the requirements file.

requirements.txt:

```
# fcm-django
fcm-django < 1
```

You might want to consider [Migration to v1.0](https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#migration-to-v1-0).

To install the latest version on the development server, run `pip install` with the upgrade flag:

```sh
pip install -U fcm-django
```

To downgrade to a lower version:

```sh
pip install 'fcm-django<1'
```

---

Usage in `fcm-django < 1`: https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/archive-pyfcm/

```py
devices.send_message(title=self.title, body=self.description, click_action=self.link)
```

Usage in the latest version of `fcm-django`: https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```py
from firebase_admin.messaging import Message, Notification

devices.send_message(
    Message(
        notification=Notification(title=self.title, body=self.description),
        android=AndroidNotification(click_action=self.link),
        apns=APNSConfig(payload=APNSPayload(aps=Aps(category=self.link))),
    )
)
```

Comment: Fixed the wrong import ([xtrinch/fcm-django#179](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django/pull/179)).